# How to have conditional redirect for nginx?

Tags: nginx, redirect

I have a situation like this:

Consider, I have 2 articles:

- https://example.com/old-article.html
- https://example.com/new-article.html

I have a redirect in nginx:

```
location /old-article.html {
   return 301 http://$server_name/new-article.html;
}
```

My purpose is for people from outside of my site, go to old-article, they will then be redirected to new-article. But when they are using my website, they go to the old-article, they will be taken to the exact old-article.

But with the redirect in nginx above, I make the visitor go to only new-article, like a loop.

Can this be possible to do with nginx? If, yes, how can I do?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What's the difference between "clicking the link" and "go to old-url"? It seems to be the same thing: The client's browser sends a request to your server for the old-url. You could look at the referer header to see if the request originated from one of your own pages.

Comment: Maybe I did not explain clearly. I have 2 scenarios: 1. user access my site with old-url from google search, other websites, the old-url will redirect them to new-url. 2 users who are browsing my site, they click the old-url, and they con actually go to the old-url, not new-url anymore. Hope, this explains clearer.

Comment: I understand the concept of looking for the referer header and use that to redirect. But I don't know how to write the nginx rules...

Answer (score 0):

This could be achieved by using nginx `map` feature. Define the following `map` in `http` level:

```
map $http_referer $redirectold {
    default 1;
    "~^http://example.com/" 0;
}
```

And in main configuration:

```
server {
    if ($redirectold) {
        rewrite ^/old-article.html http://example.com/new-article.html permanent;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Will try out.